# Matrix size incompatible: ln[0] : [1:43264], ln[16,512]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to build a model that classifies and predicts words from the users lips. With adverb a total of 142657 images that have been preproccessed using the dataset of videos of individual speakers  but I get this error when running the model and doesnt even get past the first epoch
heres my code

```py
import os
from silence_tensorflow import silence_tensorflow

silence_tensorflow()
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Input, Conv2D, \
MaxPooling2D, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(0)
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')


 class AdverbNet(object):
   def __init__(self):
       self.Model = Sequential()
       self.build()

   def build(self):
       self.Model.add(Input(name='the_input', shape=(224, 224, 1), batch_size=16,   dtype='float32'))
       self.Model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', name='convo2'))
       self.Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
       self.Model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', name='convo3'))
       self.Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
       self.Model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', name='convo4'))
       self.Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
       self.Model.add(Flatten())

       self.Model.add(Dense(512))
       self.Model.add(Dropout(0.5))
       self.Model.add(BatchNormalization(scale=False))
       self.Model.add(Activation('relu'))
       self.Model.add(Dropout(0.5))
       self.Model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

   def summary(self):
       self.Model.summary()




if __name__ == "__main__":
   common_path = 'C:/Users/Loide/Desktop/Liphy/'
   C = AdverbNet()
   C.Model.compile(optimizer="Adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
   C.Model.summary()

with tf.device('/device:GPU:0')  
   batch_size = 16
   epochs = 32
   train_dir = common_path + 'Images/Adverb/'
   test_dir = common_path + 'Images/Adverb/'
   checkpoint_path = common_path + 'SavedModels/Adverb/'

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)  # Generator for  training data generate training anD test set
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
    directory=train_dir,
    shuffle=True,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='grayscale')
    

test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)  # Generator for  test data
test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
    directory=test_dir,
    shuffle=False,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='grayscale')

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy',
                                                patience=10,
                                                restore_best_weights=True,
                                                baseline=0.45)
history = C.Model.fit(train_data_gen,
                          steps_per_epoch=8916,  # Number of images // Batch size
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=test_data_gen,
    validation_steps=187,
    callbacks=[callback])

C.Model.save(checkpoint_path, save_format='tf')
```

**and I get the following error **

```
[Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [1,43264], In[1]: [16,512]
         [[{{node gradient_tape/sequential/dense/MatMul/MatMul_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1179]
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have two matrices (one 1x43265 and one 16x512). You try to multiply them but its product is mathematically not defined. You need one matrix to be a (a x b) matrix and the other to be a (b x c) matrix. Thats why your program can't run. If your images are a test dataset try to follow the instructions step by step. If not, your preprocessing is probably bad.